# Создание трансляции видео потока с рабочего стола/веб камеры на C# ? Как реализовать?

Tags: c#, wpf, streaming

Как реализовать cоздание трансляции видео потока с  рабочего стола/веб камеры на C# ?

Comment: Например, 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/142617/
и 
https://habrahabr.ru/post/177793/